# Why are images not accesible on S3 when they do exist.

Tags: amazon-s3

We built an application that uploads rendered images to S3. Then we return all the image URLs to a third party and the third party pulls down all the rendered files. The problem is that third party is getting an error *couldn't fetch rendered file* which means the URL we gave them doesn't return an image.

If they were to try a second time, with the same URLs, everything works fine. And if we were to try to load the image URL via our browser, it's there.

We originally thought it had to do with propagation across S3. Where our region had the file, but the third parties region didn't have the image yet. So we put in a 10 minute delay; which didn't help. We can increase this to 30 minutes or an hour, but that makes it harder to test and Amazon says it takes only seconds.

Any ideas as to what might be happening? Why would an image that exists, that has the proper permissions, not return the first time the third party service asks for it?

Answer (score 1):

this problem as you stated doesn't make sense, because if there is no difference between a client downloading the file using a browser or your third party.

The only thing that comes to my mind is the url construction and access through https.

You can create the object url using **https**://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<file name>, you will probably get the following error:

**curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK**

Or using firefox you get:
[image: This Connection is Untrusted]

This problem can be easily resolved by the user ignoring the certificate error, but if the third party is using an API, this problem might be hidden by using a bad exception handling.

Would you have more information about how the third party is trying to retrieve this file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know much about the third party, however they haven't had an issue in about a month so I'm hoping they worked out their issue.